# How to compare a value in the response with earlier values in soapUI?

Tags: groovy, soapui, security-testing

I'm working with soapUI and groovy to do a test whether a particular value regenerates again?

I'll have a soapUI request with JSON which gives a id in the response, i should extract tat id and store it in a dynamic location so that the when i run the test case again, i should be able to compare the prev id. if it both matches then the test case should fail, if not then the new value should be added and the when the test case runs now, it should compare the prev two values.

This goes on for a min of  10000 runs. so 10000th id should compare with all the 9999th id to check for repetition. If it exists, it should fail else the test should pass.

Please help me.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you tried to use a file system for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

March, 2013...wow..sorry for the late answer and hopefully you were able to find an answer to this question.

I do not have access to soapUI right so i cannot offer code for this answer but off the top of my head i would say..instead of saving the value in the dynamic location store it in a test suite, test case or project level property and each time you want to compare..just read that value and compare.

I understand you are going to have to store 10000 times so instead of creating so many properties, store the values in a list or map and store that map in the properties. Every time you need to check the value, you access that property, find what you are looking for an compare.

I'll have access to soapUI tomorrow so i'll try to write some code for you.

Comment: I don't know if you are still working with something like this, but I'm also trying to store a list, but apparently soapui only accepts strings in the properties.